# How do I get single layer Latitude and Longitude for constant Time and Depth from a NetCDF file?

Tags: java, gis, netcdf

I am trying to read a NetCDF file with 4 parameters (**Time, Depth, Latitude, Longitude**), I want to read the file at a constant Time and depth.

Right now I am reading the whole file and then getting the values in a **4D grid** and then parsing the grid to get the values at constant depth and time into a **2D array**

```
//I have read the values of time and depth in TimeArr and depthArr respectively

int depthIndex = binarySearchInArray(depthArr, d);
int timeIndex = binarySearchInArray(timeArr, d);

ArrayFloat.D4 tempArr = (ArrayFloat.D4) v.read();
float[][] grid = new float[(int) latArr.getSize()][(int) lonArr.getSize()];
for (int i = 0; i < latArr.getSize(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lonArr.getSize(); j++) {
         grid[i][j] = tempArr.get(timeIndex, depthIndex, i, j);
    }
}
return grid;
```

The line `ArrayFloat.D4 tempArr = (ArrayFloat.D4) v.read();` takes a lot of time to read the file if it's too large. 
Also, it is pointless to read all the dimensions when I need it for only one.

Is there a way to directly read a file along 2 dimensions only (with 2 dimensions, Time and Depth, kept constant)?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can just read the data you need would be to use the `read(int[] origin, int[] shape)` method on the `Variable`:

```
// define the indexes where you would like the array
// subset to start
int[] origin = new int[] {timeIndex, depthIndex, 0, 0};

// define the overall size of the read to be done, starting
// at origin
int[] size = new int[] {1, 1, latSize, lonSize};

// read the subset
Array data4D = v.read(origin, size);

// remove any dimensions of size 1
Array data2D = data4D.reduce();
```

where `latSize` and `lonSize` are the size of those dimensions, respectively.

For more information, as well as for a few other approaches, see the [netCDF-Java tutorial](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/tutorial/NetcdfFile.html) (specifically the **Reading data from a Variable** section).

Cheers!